# Tool for UI mockups and screen navigation of mobile apps

Tags: android, iphone, user-interface

Basically I saw [this](http://www.groosoft.com/blueprint/) app and I'm looking for a similar app but not for tablet but for desktop pc (or online).
Really don't care if the mockup look is for iPhone or Android or if ir worth money.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should post this at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [this](http://keynotopia.com) from keynotopia. It includes templates for Android, iPhone, iPad, BlackBerry, Windows phone, web, Facebook, OS X, and Windows.

The templates run in Keynote for Mac, or Power Point for Windows, and they are excellent.  You can choose from wireframe, sketch, or Hi-Res versions of each of the templates.  You layout your design in Keynote (or Powerpoint), and can hook actions together to make your design look/feel functional.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [ForeUI](http://www.ForeUI.com/), which can create UI mockups and define interactions for web/desktop/mobile applications.  You can also find an downloadable iPhone library in [ForeUI store](http://www.foreui.com/store/).

Answer (score 0):

Balsamiq is also a good UI mock-up tool which contains the libraries for lot of platforms.
You can have a try with the following link,
https://balsamiqgdrive.appspot.com